# End execution of playbook with a custom message

Tags: ansible

How do I end execution on a playbook with a custom message. This is how my playbook looks like, which is in roles/oracledbsw_install/tasks/main.yaml

```
- block:
    - name: "Check if Binaries already installed"
      shell: grep "{{ oracle_home }}"  {{ oracle_inventory }}/ContentsXML/inventory.xml
      register: binary_available

    - meta: end_play
      when: binary_available < 1

- name: display pre database software install message
  debug:
    msg:
      - 'Oracle Database Software 19c Installation started for Single Instance at {{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}:'
```

This task "display pre database software install message" shouldn't execute if my end_play works. But it looks like its not. The idea is any task listed after the end play should not be executed.

Comment: add a `register` of the output value from `end_play`, and then use success indicating value to write a `when` right after the task `debug` above. I also would recommend to move the custom message task `debug` within the block scope.

Comment: I thought that endplay will work like an exit condition from shell script can it be not used in such a way?